# AWS CLI covert pdf to sdf or json for CloudSearch index

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-cloudsearch

I am working on a document search tool using CloudSearch in AWS. The index only takes XML or JSON. I would like to index the document content along with metadata, but can't figure out how to convert the pdf (and Excel) files into a format that CloudSearch accepts. I have seen references to `cs-import-documents`, but that doesn't appear in my CLI.

[image]

Has anyone run into this? Or can anyone point me to another method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For any interested parties, `cs-import-documents` no longer exists. This was part of an older version of the AWC CLI, but has since been deprecated and not replaced.

Comment: Super lame considering you get the conversion behaviour when going via AWS Console. For CLI/SDK I ended up writing my own code to generate the JSON.